# Which compounds react positively in the aniline dye test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, phenols, dye

I read that to test for the presence of phenol groups in an organic compound the aniline dye test can be performed. If the solution has phenol present it gives a red or orange precipitate to confirm the presence, however as a side note it was mentioned that this test is applicable for the detection of small quantities of phenols, which have a free para position. Why is it so?

Comment: Umm, why don't you just read up about synthesis of azo compounds? That should make things clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the aniline is converted to a diazonium halide salt in the presence of acid and sodium nitrite, per this [reference](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/diazotisation.shtm).

Then, the diazonium salt reacts with the phenol to give an azo compound, per this [reference (see the section entitled *Coupling reactions of diazonium ions*](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Phenols/Reactivity_of_Phenols/Making_an_Azo_Dye_from_Phenol)

Note that the diazonium ion is shown reacting with the *para* position of the phenol. That is because the -OH group in phenol is an *ortho,para*-director ([reference)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrophilic_aromatic_directing_groups), meaning that it enhances the nucleophilicity of the *ortho* and *para* positions on the phenol ring. However, the *para* position is significantly more nucleophilic because of the relative lack of steric hindrance in comparison to the *ortho* positions, which are hindered by the proximity of the -OH group.

So, having a free *para* position on the phenol means that the phenol is especially reactive towards electrophiles, including the diazonium salt in this example, meaning that it will react faster and in higher yields - increasing the sensitivity of the aniline dye test.